# RegExp: combine patterns using alternation operator or execute regular expression several times

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a string to match one of the several patterns. What is considered to be a better practice? Combine patterns with the help of alternation operator `|`:

```
const regexp = /(width)-(\d+)$|(height)-(\d+)$/
const matches = regexp.exec(string);
```

Or to execute regular expression several times with different patterns:

```
const regexp = /(width)-(\d+)$/
const regexp2 = /(height)-(\d+)$/
let matches = regexp.exec(string);
let matches2 = regexp.exec(string);
```

The thing I like, when executing regular expression several times is that resulted array will always have the same structure, while using combined pattern the result would be different for matching **height** and **width** because **width** will match first two capturing parenthesis, but **height** the last two.

For example if string is `width-20` the result would be:

```
[ 'width-20',
  'width',
  '20',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: 'width-20' 
]
```

And for `height-20`:

```
[ 'height-20',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  'height',
  '20',
  index: 0,
  input: 'height-20' 
]
```

But what is a better way from performance point of view?

Comment: Or `/(width|height)-(\d+)$/`.

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 but still slower

Comment: @Yehia Award have you tested this way too?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Yes I have Tested it is slower than your second option but faster than your first

Comment: How many iterations are involved that you need to worry about performance? The answer is talking about a million iterations, but if you only have a thousand, or a hundred then it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I have Edited my answer

Comment: @nnnn thanks, your option looks cleaner. When I'll realise the real amount of iterations that would be involved I'll make the decision based on your considerations.

Comment: There are no rules or stupid "best practices", all depends of your subject string(s) and eventually where the code is executed *(browser X or Y, node ver x,y,z)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I thought the first option was faster but after some Testing at `1E6` iterations I reached the Conclusion that using OR in RegExp is slower **~30-40%**

**was able to solve 1 million iteration in 75-99ms**

```
const regexp = /(width)-(\d+)$/
const regexp2 = /(height)-(\d+)$/
let matches = regexp.exec(string);
let matches2 = regexp.exec(string);
```

**was able to solve 1 million iteration in 120-140ms**

```
const regexp = /(width)-(\d+)$|(height)-(\d+)$/
const matches = regexp.exec(string);
```

EDIT

using the Third option prived by @nnnnnn :

**was able to solve 1 million iteration in 110-125ms**

```
const regexp = /(width|height)-(\d+)$/
const matches = regexp.exec(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if the tests results would be the same, if there would be more patterns. I'll try to make some test for my own later.

Comment: Glad it helped you somehow ), it helped me too to figure out that | can have performance impact if not handled well )